# Javascript - onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick

first time posting here, but god know's I use this site to search for problems all the time :P Well, I'm having a problem of my own now that I can't seem to figure out easily searching around Google, and after playing with it for about 2 hours, I've finally decided to post a question and see what you guys think.

What I'm trying to accomplish here is to have a button that appears over a div when you hover over it that, when clicked, opens an editing pane. The button appears over the div correctly, but for some reason I cannot seem to make the onclick function work to save my life lol. Here's the code I'm working with. If it's not enough, please let me know and I'll add a little more sauce. :P

```
function place_widget(name, properties){
//bbox
var pleft = properties[0];
var ptop = properties[1];
var width = properties[2];
var height = properties[3];
var pright = pleft + width;
var pbottom = pleft + height;
var bbox = [pleft, ptop, pright, pbottom];
boxes[name] = bbox;

//ID's
var id = 'widget_' + name;
var editspanid = id + "_editspan";
var editbuttonid = id + "_editbutton";
var editpaneid = id + "_editpane";

//Creating Elements
var div = "<div id='" + id + "' class='widget' onmouseover='widget_hover(event);' onmouseout='widget_out(event);'>";
var editbutton = "<a id='" + editbuttonid + "' href='#'><img onclick='toggleEdit;' src='../images/edit_button.png'></a>";
var editspan = "<span id='" + editspanid + "' class='editspan'>" + editbutton + "</span>";
var editpane = "<span id='" + editpaneid + "' class='editpane'>:)</span>";
div += editspan + editpane + "</div>";
body.innerHTML += div;

//Configuring Elements
var editspanelement = document.getElementById(editspanid);
var editbuttonelement = document.getElementById(editbuttonid);
editbuttonelement.onclick = alert; //Does nothing.
var editpaneelement = document.getElementById(editpaneid);
var mainelement = document.getElementById('widget_' + name);
mainelement.style.left = (pleft + leftmost) + "px";
mainelement.style.top = (ptop + topmost) + "px";
mainelement.style.width = width;
mainelement.style.height = height;
getContentsAJAX(name);
}
```

Sorry for the ugly code :P Anyone have any idea why the onclick function isn't working?

Also, a bit of extra info: If I open up firebug and put in :

```
document.getElementById('widget_Text_01_editbutton').onclick = alert;
```

When I click the button, I get:

```
uncaught exception: [Exception... "Illegal operation on WrappedNative prototype object" nsresult: "0x8057000c (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_OP_ON_WN_PROTO)" location: "native frame :: <unknown filename> :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 0" data: no]
```

I'm not exactly sure what that means off hand.

Thanks!

Comment: A general comment regarding posting JS / HTML code: while some people can sometimes just look at the code and spot some of the mistakes, it would help others to help you if you made it more accessible by either 1) posting something whole that one can simply copy into a file and open with a browser and/or 2) putting it on http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: Aye. I'll definitely consider that in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try changing:

```
<img onclick='toggleEdit;' src='../images/edit_button.png'>
```

to:

```
<img onclick='toggleEdit();' src='../images/edit_button.png'>
```

Also, is "alert" a function you wrote?

Comment: Hmm. That would call toggleEdit at the initialization of onclick and return the value of it as the onclick event if I'm not mistaken. Not quite what I'm trying to do. I honestly didn't realize I still had that onclick in there :P I've been trying wayyy too many methods trying to get this to work. Thanks!

Comment: No, it's in quotes so the string will get evaled at click time.

Comment: No, that would create an anonymous function that calls toggleEdit() and binds that function to the onclick event handler of the image.

Comment: Ahh I see. Sorry for the hardheadedness :P The toggleEdit(); didn't work, though I changed that to alert and it worked. So I'm guessing there's a problem with my toggleEdit function now. That's on my end though. It seems like your solution did the trick! :) Thank you very much! Though, I'm still a little curious as to why the buttonelement.onclick function didn't work.

Comment: Yea, window.alert is not a Javascript function and can't be used as a callback for a click handler.  You'd have to wrap it in a Javascript function, something like `.onclick = function() { alert(''); };`

Answer (score 3):

Start by changing this:

```
editbuttonelement.onclick = alert; //Does nothing.
```

to this:

```
editbuttonelement.onclick = function() {alert("Got a click");};
```

and then change this:

```
var editbutton = "<a id='" + editbuttonid + "' href='#'><img onclick='toggleEdit;' src='../images/edit_button.png'></a>";
```

to this:

```
var editbutton = "<a id='" + editbuttonid + "' href='#'><img onclick='toggleEdit();' src='../images/edit_button.png'></a>";
```

What you are clicking on?  The image or the link or the span?  Do you know which is getting the click event?

Comment: That's actually another problem I was having earlier. I had done something like that, but when creating the anonymous function, firefox was telling me the function must have a name (odd huh?). But I just put in what you requested, and it doesn't give me that error, though happens still. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('widget_Text_01_editbutton').onclick = alert;
```

causes `illegal invocation` because it is trying to set `this` to something else (the element) than `window` inside `alert`.

```
alert.call( {} )
//TypeError: Illegal invocation

alert.bind( window ).call( {} )
//works
```

So either:

```
document.getElementById('widget_Text_01_editbutton').onclick = alert.bind( window );
```

or even better as the above will only work in some browsers:

```
document.getElementById('widget_Text_01_editbutton').onclick = function(){alert();};
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Sadly, when putting this into FireBug, I'm still given the exact same error when clicking the button. Also, it comes to no avail in the code either. This is a real stumper, eh? :P Thanks!

Comment: It's not the same error, the error you are now getting is that there is nothing to alert (which is firefox specific, chrome is fine alerting nothing). Try `alert.bind( window, "123" );`

Answer (score -1):

It will help you in executing.

```
<img onclick='toggleEdit;' src='../images/edit_button.png'>
```