# Add function to img button

Tags: javascript, html, image, function, button

I would like to know how to add function to an image button - this code is different to other posts like mine is based around input type img not img src

```
*<input type="image" src="llama.png" name="saveForm" class="btTxt submit" id="saveForm" />*
```

I am trying to make the image into a Clicker meaning I am using a clickFunction to do so. Any suggestions?

Comment: The `onclick` property?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923350/javascript-onclick)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a .click() event to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374562/how-do-i-add-a-click-event-to-an-image)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript, add onclick event programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13229208/javascript-add-onclick-event-programmatically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

```js
document.getElementById('saveForm').addEventListener('click', function(){
  console.log('you have clicked', this.name);
});
```

```html
<input type="image" src="llama.png" name="saveForm" class="btTxt submit" id="saveForm" />
```

Comment: Thank you I'm new to javascript/html

Comment: @NovaBot, you are most welcome. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to the `click` event by doing something like:

```js
function foo() {
  console.log("I am called");
}
```

```html
<input type="image" src="llama.png" name="saveForm" onclick="foo()" class="btTxt submit" id="saveForm" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="image" src="llama.png" name="saveForm" class="btTxt submit" id="saveForm" onclick="callFunction() />

<script>
callFunction(){
  alert('Calling');
}

</script>
```

**Or You can user EventListener**

```
document.getElementById('saveForm').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  alert('Calling');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple solution using `onclick` event

```js
 function myImg() {
  alert("clicked");
}
```

```html
 <input type="image" name="saveForm"  src="xyz.png" onclick="myImg()" class="btTxt submit" id="saveForm" />
```