# JS isn't running the do-while loop

Tags: javascript, loops, do-while

I'm trying to make a small js game, but I had no clue what is wrong here.

Instead of waiting for the click of the user, it runs until the end and gives the alert of the gameOver() function.

Why is it not waiting? and Why isn't it looping until the user clicks on the lastChild of the container element?

```js
/************************************************
 * Positioning function
 ************************************************/
function gamePostitioning () {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 350 ));
    var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 350 ));
    return {x, y};
 };

/************************************************
 * LeftSide smiling faces generator
 ************************************************/
var numberOfFaces = 0;
var theLeftSide = document.getElementById('leftSide');

function generateFaces() {
    theLeftSide.innerHTML = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfFaces; i++) {
        
        var imgElement = document.createElement('IMG');

        imgElement.src = "smile.png";
        imgElement.style.top = gamePostitioning().y + "px";
        imgElement.style.left = gamePostitioning().x + "px";

        theLeftSide.appendChild(imgElement);
    }
    /* cheating */
    console.log(theLeftSide.lastChild);
 };
 
/************************************************
 * Cloning the left-1 to RightSide
 ************************************************/
  var theRightSide = document.getElementById('rightSide');

  function cloneGeneration() {
  
      theRightSide.removeChild(theRightSide.firstChild)
      var cloned = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
      cloned.id =""; 
      theRightSide.appendChild(cloned).removeChild(cloned.lastChild);
 };

/************************************************
 * GAME OVER function + local store the best result
 ************************************************/
function gameOver() {
    var current = numberOfFaces/5

    if( !best || best < current){
        best = localStorage.setItem('best', current);
    }else{
        best = localStorage.getItem('best');
    }

    alert(
        'Game OVER!\n\n' +
        'Current level: ' + current + '. level\n\n' +
        'Your best result: ' + best + '. level'
        );
 }
 
numberOfFaces += 5;
generateFaces(),
cloneGeneration();


do {
    theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = function toNextLevel(event){ 
        event.stopPropagation();
        numberOfFaces += 5;

        generateFaces();
        cloneGeneration();
    }
} while ( theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick ) 

gameOver();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>.JS Matching Game</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12" id="header">
                    <h2> Matching Game</h2>
                    <p>Click on the extra smiling face in the white box!</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row" id="gameSpace">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div id="leftSide">
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="row" id="gameSpace">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div id="rightSide">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: onClick is not a continuous condition. It only fires when someone....clicks. And you need to add it to your HTML, not your JS. There are a lot of good articles on this topic out there if you're interested.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript - onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923350/javascript-onclick)

Comment: Get rid of the loop and call `gameOver()` inside the onclick function if your conditions are met

Comment: if I get rid of the loop, how will I repeat the functions until the click is right? @charlietfl

Comment: To be honest there isn't enough known from what is shown to answer that

Comment: @charlietfl I've posted the whole. What about now?

Comment: Sorry but I am still not clear what the expected behavior is expected here. Side note -- you can't repeat element id in a page

Answer (score 0):

`gameOver` runs at the end of the script, so it would naturally end the game. You need a condition to see if the game have ended. Is your intention that the user have X number of clicks before the game ends? In that case, I would go a bit differently.

Also, you don't need to loop an event propagation. It will fire when the event occurs. I made a few changed in the code, but also had to create two TEMP methods for storage, because Stackoverflow doesn't allow for localstorage.

I changed in the event method, and also in `gameOver`. It doesn't seem like the game is finished, but I tagged everything I changed in the code. You had an issue with using the variable `best` in `gameOver` which I corrected.

```js
/************************************************
 * Positioning function
 ************************************************/
function gamePostitioning() {
  var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 350));
  var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 350));
  return {
    x,
    y
  };
};

/************************************************
 * LeftSide smiling faces generator
 ************************************************/
var numberOfFaces = 0;
var theLeftSide = document.getElementById('leftSide');

function generateFaces() {
  theLeftSide.innerHTML = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfFaces; i++) {

    var imgElement = document.createElement('IMG');

    imgElement.src = "smile.png";
    imgElement.style.top = gamePostitioning().y + "px";
    imgElement.style.left = gamePostitioning().x + "px";

    theLeftSide.appendChild(imgElement);
  }
  /* cheating */
  console.log(theLeftSide.lastChild);
};

/************************************************
 * Cloning the left-1 to RightSide
 ************************************************/
var theRightSide = document.getElementById('rightSide');

function cloneGeneration() {

  theRightSide.removeChild(theRightSide.firstChild)
  var cloned = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
  cloned.id = "";
  theRightSide.appendChild(cloned).removeChild(cloned.lastChild);
};

/************************************************
 * GAME OVER function + local store the best result
 ************************************************/
function gameOver() {
  var current = numberOfFaces / 5

  // DECLARE 'best' as a variable, and read it directly from localStorage
  var best = getBestFromLocalStorageTemp() || 0;

  if (!best || best < current) {
    storeBestFromLocalStorageTemp(current);
  }

  alert(
    'Game OVER!\n\n' +
    'Current level: ' + current + '. level\n\n' +
    'Your best result: ' + best + '. level'
  );
}

var storageBestTemp;

function getBestFromLocalStorageTemp() {
  return storageBestTemp;
//  return localStorage.getItem('best')
}

function storeBestInLocalStorageTemp(value) {
  storageBestTemp = value;
  // return localStorage.setItem('best', value);
}

numberOfFaces += 5;
generateFaces();
cloneGeneration();


// do {
theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = function toNextLevel(event) {
    // event.stopPropagation();
    numberOfFaces += 5;

    generateFaces();
    cloneGeneration();
    
    let CONDITION = true;
    
    // I MOVED THIS INSIDE THIS LISTENER
    // NEEDS A CONDITION TO NOT ACTIVATE
    if (CONDITION) {
      gameOver();
    }
}
    // } while ( theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick )
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>.JS Matching Game</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12" id="header">
        <h2> Matching Game</h2>
        <p>Click on the extra smiling face in the white box!</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" id="gameSpace">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div id="leftSide">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" id="gameSpace">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div id="rightSide">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: okay, this makes sense, but how can I repeat the generating and copying functions until the user is clicking on the lastChild?

Comment: I would like if you could edit your OP and write a) what the game is about b) how a "turn" should be executed (what is the expected behavior of the user, and what is the response) and c) how the game ends. Because I don't understand what your game is about, just by reading the code.

Comment: a) I'm learning javascript, and I'd like to make this game.

b) A turn should be like: There are 2 div-s, in one of them 5 smiley is generated at a random position within a container. In the other, js copies them, except the last one. User should click on the difference, the extra in the first div. If s/he clicked on the extra, the next level should be executed in the same order as before just with +5 more faces.